Is there an "ESA Astronaut Alexander Gerst Observatory" in Künzelsau, Germany? If so, what's it like?

The answer to the 2018 Space SE question What is astronaut Alexander Gerst signaling with this K-shaped hand signal? remains as elusive as his smile is enchanting.
One currently deleted answer there mentions that in addition to being a graduate of Karlsruhe Institute of Technology he is also from the town of Künzelsau.
From the (Google translated from German) 21 May 2019
KLR news item Welcome back: Künzelsau celebrates its astronaut Alexander Gerst near the end:

Alexander Gerst is known to millions of people primarily through his activities on the social networks Twitter and Facebook , where he reports on his two missions into space and his commitment on Earth as "Asto_Alex". The fascinating experiences of the famous Künzelsau resident have already been permanently recorded in the form of a space exhibition in the town hall of the town of around 15,000 inhabitants. A new observatory will ensure that the people of Künzelsau can continue to keep a close eye on the stars in the near future. The groundbreaking ceremony for the "ESA Astronaut Alexander Gerst Observatory" also took place together with the guests of honor on May 18, 2019.

A quick search for (the original German) "ESA-Astronaut Alexander Gerst Sternwarte" has led me to https://www.sternwarte-schloss-stetten.de/ but I'm not sure what that is.
So I'd like to ask:
Question: Is there an "ESA Astronaut Alexander Gerst Observatory" in Künzelsau, Germany? If so, what's it like?

It is yet to be built
The page you link, is for the e.V. which is basically a German non-profit association or club for local astronomy-interested people. The goal appears to be to construct an educational facility and small observatory.
The most recent information I can find about this project is this governmental land planning document from mid 2022:

The white building footprint on the right is labeled "Sternwarte geplant und genehmigt" which translates to "Observatory planned and approved". If you look at the coordinates of where this is (49.2682, 9.7784) via maps, you can see that, as of 2024, it is an empty lot.
